# Adding specialized functionality to instance of a reducer factory

Tags: redux, factory

In order to decrease code duplication in the redux-related part of my app, I have come up with reducer factories in order to group repetative logic into an abstract reducer which is then turned into concrete reducer instances by passing `name` param to the factory.

ReduxFactory/reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    foo: null
}

function reducerFactory(name = '') {
    return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            
            case `${name}_DO_SOMETHING`: {
                 return state
            }

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}

export default reducerFactory;
```

Then I have two modules for which I build instances of a reducer factory:

fileA.js

```
import reducerFactory from './ReduxFactory/reducer'


const reducer = reducerFactory('OBJECT_A')
```

fileB.js

```
import reducerFactory from './ReduxFactory/reducer'


const reducer = reducerFactory('OBJECT_B')
```

Now imagine that on objects of type B I need to implement some ad-hoc functionality, which I do not want to include into the general reducer factory body because it is too specialized. Is there any valid JS code pattern to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly I think you can do the following:

```
function reducerFactory(name = '', extras = (x) => x) {
  return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case `${name}_DO_SOMETHING`: {
        return state;
      }

      default:
        return extras(state, action);
    }
  };
}

const reducer = reducerFactory(
  'OBJECT_B',
  (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'extra') {
      //return changed state
    }
    return state;
  }
);
```